# Post method not working with Class Object in Play 2.5

Tags: java, playframework, resteasy, playframework-2.5

I try to call Post method from PostMan but not able to call.

Controller File :

```
public class UserController extends Controller{

     public Result getAll() {
         List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
         users.add(new User("Vinit", "vinitsolanki@yahoo.com", 25));
         users.add(new User("Jaimin", "jaimin@yahoo.com", 25));
         return ok(Json.toJson(users));
     }

     public Result get(Long id) {

         User user = new User();
         user.setId(id);
         user.setName("Vinit");
         user.setEmail("vinitsolanki@yahoo.com");
         user.setAge(25);

         return ok(Json.toJson(user));

    }

     public Result create(User user){

         return ok(Json.toJson(user));
     }
}
```

Route File :

```
#User
#Method.Type    url             mapping with method
GET             /user           controllers.UserController.getAll
GET             /user/:id       controllers.UserController.get(id: Long)
POST            /user           controllers.UserController.create
```

both get methods `/url` and `/user/:id` working fine, but i am little confused on post `/user`. I tried code as in file, i got above error.

```
missing arguments for method create in class UserController;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Comment: your method is expecting a User object but you are not passing it.

Comment: i pass this json {"id":10,"name":"vinit","email":"vinit@yahoo.com"}

Comment: but how will the method know to convert this json to User Object?

Comment: yes i am confused on this, i have used spring earlier, in spring i have used Jackson literary, so which literary/configuration required in Play 2.5

Comment: I can get User Object with the use of request().body().asJson(). Is this right way to get User Object ? `public Result create(){
   User user = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), User.class);
   return ok(Json.toJson(user));
   
  }`

Comment: Yes you can do that, It should work

Comment: Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do this.

You can use the **default body parser** (this is the way you mentioned in your comment):

```
public Result create() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    User user = Json.fromJson(json, User.class);
    return ok(Json.toJson(user));
}
```

The second method is to use an **explicit body parser**:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result create() {
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    User user = // some logic here
    return ok(body.asJson());
}
```

*Bonus:* instead of `BodyParser.Json` you can use `BodyParser.TolerantJson`: the same like Json, but does not validate that the Content-Type header is JSON.

For further information you can take a look at the [Play documentation regarding body parsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers)